# Access to localstorage from Vaadin flow

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I need to save user preferences in the browser's local storage. How can I access localStorage from my Vaadin code?

I tried with https://vaadin.com/directory/component/clientstorage but it looks that this addon supports only vaadin 7-8 versions, and I am using version 12.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no server side Java API for local storage.
>   But you may call JavaScript on the client side to deal with it directly.
>   - Denis Anisimov, [from a github 'ticket'](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4852)

You will have to find out how to access localStorage using javascript. There are many tutorials in the net how to do that so I won't be explaining it here.

If you don't know how to add javascript to your view in Vaadin and then call it, please see [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v12/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-importing.html) and [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/advanced/tutorial-execute-javascript.html)

Comment: Well, I'm aware of how to access local storage from JS but how can I execute JS code from Vaadin java code and get JS function's result? To be more precisely I need to get client preferences from local storage and hide or unhide columns in my Grid component/

Comment: I have no real experience in using JS in Vaadin. Sadly I cannot help you further, all I know is what's already written in the links in my answer.

Comment: Something like that: `UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("return $0.get...", component.getElement()).then(result -> System.out.println(result.asNumber()));`